# There are 20 towns in a certain country, and every pair of them is connected by an air route. How many air routes are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This problem is from *Mathematical Circles (Russian experience)* by Dmitri Fomin, Sergey Genkin and Ilia Itenberg.

The major problem I am facing is that I am not able to understand what does " **every pair of them is connected** " mean.
I suppose it means:
If I take any two random towns, I will be able to find an air route in between. In such a scenario, I am unable to understand the solution given below.

The problem is from combinatorics section.
The solution says :

> Every route connects two towns. We can choose any of the 20 towns in the country (say A) as the beginning of a route, and we have 19 remaining towns to choose the end of the route (say B) from. Multiplying, we have 20×19=380. However, this calculation counted every route AB twice : when A was chosen as the beginning of the route, and when B was chosen as the beginning. Hence, number of routes is 380/2=190

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe more what you don't understand from the quoted solution?

Comment: They intend "every pair of them is connected" to mean that there is a direct route between each pair of cities. So the task is just to count the (unordered) pairs.

Comment: 20*19 counts all the ordered pairs, so for each two cities A and B it counts AB and BA, but you only want to count the route, not the one way tickets. That is you're interested in doubleton sets {A,B} instead of the ordered pairs (A,B) and (B,A). But it seems the answer is essentially that esplanation. Don't worry -- combinatorics is not easy, and it takes some practice to familiarize yourself with these concepts.

Comment: Try with 5 cities, and make a picture : Starting with each city, drag a line to each other city and look what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to count the number of routes in a city with $4$ towns.
By brute-force, we know that there are $6$ routes.
Using the method provided in your solution,
we can count these routes as follows:

1. Choose a town as the starting town and then choose another town as the target town, and count the route from the starting town and the target town
2. Count all the ways we can do step 1
3. Adjust the result so that it does not overcount

What are all the ways we can do step 1?
First, we have $4$ towns to choose as the starting town.
For each starting town we have chosen,
there are always $3$ towns that can be chosen as the target town.
Therefore, there are $4\times 3=12$ routes counted in this way.

However, the routes counted are actually "directed routes",
i.e. the route from town $A$ to town $B$ is considered different from the route from town $B$ to town $A$.
But we intended to count the route between $A$ and $B$ only once,
neglecting the direction.
Therefore, we have to adjust the result.

Note that for each route in between any two towns $A$ and $B$,
we have counted this route exactly twice,
namely from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$.
Therefore,
if we divide the result by $2$,
then we obtain the correct result:
$12/2=6$.

Now, simply change the number from $4$ to $20$,
and we get $20\cdot 19/2=190$.

---

In general, the number of ways to choose $m$ objects from a set of $n$ objects
is equal to
$$
\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}.
$$
This number is denoted $n\choose m$.
See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).